# Access contents of external resource in Appery.io

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, braintree, appery.io

I'm new to Appery.io, IONIC and AngularJS but so far it has proven to be a wicked awesome platform for streamlining development.

The problem that I'm having is with integrating external JS resources.

**What I'm trying to accomplish - Overview**

I'm trying to add [Braintree's drop-in UI](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client/javascript/v2#setup) payment processing form into one view within my app.

**The Problem**

I keep receiving "Error: Braintree.setup is not a function" error when I run the Braintree.setup() function.

**Adding the external library**

I include the script by doing the following:

1. Go to: App Settings > External Resources
2. Add script url and save it as an external library
3. Set it to enabled so that I can only load it during the payment page view

[image]

**Including the script in the view**

1. Go to "Routing"
2. Click "dependencies" for the page I want to load it on
3. Select the script > save

[image]

**Triggering Braintree.setup()**

1. Pop over to my page > scope
2. Add the setup function as listed on the Braintree website.

[image]

**Running the page**

1. Run the page and am provided this error "Error: Braintree.setup is not a function"

NOTE: I am also receiving another error before that but have no idea why. It also appears some demo apps that Appery has provided. Brownie points if you can tell me why.

[image]

The script has been loaded as I can see it in Firebug.

[image]

NOTE: On the website the code uses braintree.setup() rather than Braintree.setup(). I have switched over to Braintree.setup() because braintree.setup() was giving me an error saying that braintree was not defined. I'm not sure if Braintree is a variable defined in the resources section in which Appery assigns any values from the script to the variable.

Many thanks to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 1):

After much digging around I learned about RequireJS and AngularJS.

Turns out you have to define the script and put it inside a variable, as well as, list any dependencies.

Step 1: Create New > Javascript:type=Angular Service

Step 2: Define the dependency on the external lib url

Step 3: Return the external lib property

[image]

Step 4: Include the newly created JS file and external Lib in your page

Step 5: Call it using Apperyio.get('AngularServiceName')

[image]

Voila!

Comment: Actually it was much simpler than described above! Simply use: Apperyio.getLibrary('name_of_script'). The name of the script is the name which you titled your library in the "App Settings" page.